# Fix SSL verification fail with OpenShift Client (rhc)

Tags: ssl, certificate, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools

I have my own OpenShift Cluster. With an API running on `172.17.0.6`.
I'm trying to setup OpenShift Client Tool.

But I can't setup my client because of self signed cert.

Here is the debug:

```
$ rhc setup --server 172.17.0.6 --debug --insecure
  DEBUG: Using config file /home/gmartine/.openshift/express.conf
  DEBUG: Running greeting_stage
  OpenShift Client Tools (RHC) Setup Wizard

  This wizard will help you upload your SSH keys, set your application namespace, and
  check that other programs like Git are properly installed.
  DEBUG: Running server_stage
  DEBUG: Running login_stage
  DEBUG: Connecting to https://172.17.0.6/broker/rest/api
  DEBUG: Client supports API versions 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7
  DEBUG: Created new httpclient
  DEBUG: Request GET https://172.17.0.6/broker/rest/api
  DEBUG: SSL Verification failed -- Using self signed cert
  DEBUG:    code 403   66 ms
```

What should I do to fix this issue ?